# How to migrate in Data-stage?

Tags: migration, datastage

Can we migrate Datastage version `7.5 to 11.1.3`?

and the jobs created in version `7.5` will be compatible with the `11.1.3` version?

Comment: I think it will be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can migrate the jobs from Ascential DS 7.5 to IBM Infosphere Datastage 11.3.

For the same, you need to take the jobs .dsx export from DS 7.5 via Datastage Manager, and import the same in DS 11.3 designer corresponding projects.

The following changes would be required in the design of jobs:

1. Conversion of batch scripts to shell scripts.
2. Replace command stages with Execute command activity.
3. Replace the enterprise and API stages with connector stages if
   required.
4. Modify the pathnames, in unix version. Especially in Sequential file
   stages, change the EOF character as UNIX.
5. Change the Shelltype from 'NT' to 'UNIX' in DSExecute() function in your job properties.

After making above changes you can compile your jobs and run them.
The jobs must execute in DS 11.3 environment.
Test if any data error persists, if yes you can rectify that as per the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we migrate Datastage version 7.5 to 11.1.3?

I don't think so. You should install a fresh 11 version. This will also allow you to have the 2 instalations running at the same time so you can migrate your jobs without any interruption.

> and the jobs created in version 7.5 will be compatible with the 11.1.3 version?

Server jobs should be compatible, with some exeptions, depending how you are using the internal engine.